# How to change the content type set to new pages in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint 2013, when I create a page from "Add a page", the content type is not what I want it to be for that page. How can I change that? How does SharePoint pick the content type?

Can anyone explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint  , When we are adding any page in Pages Library it is associated with the **Page Layout** and this Page Layout is linked with the **Content Type** , we can understand this by creating new Page layout from **Design Manager** .

[image]

So , from here when you're creating a New Page layout you can assign any existing content type to the New Page Layout or you can create your own content type and assign that.

[image]

so , here we have the control to assign the content type to the particular Page Layout , and while creating the Page we can select our Page Layout from the list.

[image]

Comment: I found my issue, under master page gallery and page layouts, the page layouts had a blank value for associated content type. So I just fixed it there.